# How to fix Windows.UI.xaml.RoutedEventArgs exception?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

```
    public async static Task<RootObject> GetWeather(string username, string password)   
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var response = await http.GetAsync(postURI);  

        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));  

        var datax = (RootObject)serializer.ReadObject(ms);

        return datax;
    }
```

I have the necessary models ready and I made the function call with some    hard-coded data to test but its not working.

Comment: The title of the question appears to be unrelated to the text. Also, please be more specific than "it's not working."

Comment: Well, I kinda fixed it but I didn't know how to delete the question so its just staying there

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.